# Odd notation for `if` statement

Tags: c++

I'm looking through some legacy code where I have encountered the following `if` statement

```
if (!(foo == bar)){
    // lots of code here
}
```

What is the advantage of writing this over

```
if (foo != bar){
}
```

If it's relevant, the code base is C++.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The language is *always* relevant. It's how folk spot question that they can answer.

Comment: In a bad design, `Foo` can be a class for which `==` operator was overloaded but not `!=` one...

Comment: Yeah I thought so too. But it's a new job and don't think i can change to much.

Comment: I'm curious if second one will be faster? first one have to perform two operation separately, i.e., finding out if it is equal and then negate it. second one can stop comparing if it find a bit different. Can anyone help clarify?

Comment: @someone_smiley: yes, thanks to "fast break" on a first difference found, testing for not-equality can be "much faster". I.e. imagine a large object with a "hash" field that's computed from all other fields. If hashes equal - you still need to check everything. If hashes not equal - they are different. But then, you can implement == as !(!=), so what, ultimate free speedup? No. In this example you already see that it is NOT operation-dependent, but data-dependent. Operator== **also can return fast**, 'false' on first difference. Operator!= still will work long, when data is very similar.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl : thanks. it is clear now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They ought to be equivalent, for plain old data types they certainly are, but if the author has (unconventionally) provided an overloaded operator for `==` and not for `!=` then the second way of writing this will not be available to you.

For readability though, I think I would prefer to see

```
if (foo == bar){
    // do nothing
} else {
    // lots of code here
}
```

although the clearest way of all would be to adjust the codebase to provide the `!=` operator, and for you to adopt the second way you have written this.

Comment: A very verbose way for doing nothing (not really improving readability)

Comment: I do qualify that part as opinion-based. `(!(foo == bar))` looks like a "smell" to me.

Comment: I'd rather see `if ( !(foo == bar) )` , given that the `!=` overload is not present. Empty `if` blocks are a smell to me :)

Answer (score 2):

The requirements (concept) for a type (template parameter)  might include `EqualityComparable`, but not `NotEqualityComparable` (which does not exist as library concept as listed in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept).

The LessThanComparable concept is similar: The C++ algorithms do not need a greater than concept (it is redundant).

Comment: Yes.  That's about the only *good* reason for such a test (although even then, I would argue that changing the requirements for a template to add InequalityComparable would usually be the right thing to do.